# Should there be angled lines up my roof after new shingle installation?

Tags: roofing

Newly installed architectural shingles show a angled line from top to bottom every 3-4 feet. Is this normal?

Comment: A picture would help.

Comment: Shingles are installed in an angling, stepped pattern, but it's not clear what the problem is in your case. Please describe it better or post photos using the editor toolbar.

Comment: Generally those lines are “guidelines “ and are used to keep the shingles straight and true. What kind of line is it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. a picture) before we can really help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Sometimes roofers put down chalk lines to make sure the shingles are lining up. This will be gone the first time it rains. But a picture of what you are referring to would be helpful.

Comment: I agree with @isherwood from your description it sounds like a proper stagger of the shingles, without a photo we can only guess but I would say it sounds proper.